# Optimization problems with linq and searching within a groupby

Tags: linq, select, linq-to-sql, group-by

I have a Collection 'Col':

```
ID|Type|Type1|Type2|Count
1| a   | a   | b   |2
1| b   | a   | b   |1
2| d   | b   | d   |2
2| b   | b   | d   |2
3| x   | y   | x   |0
3| y   | y   | x   |1
```

I want to return a collection which contains for each unique ID, the possible types, the sum of each types count, and the individual count for each type

Ideally, the output should be:

```
ID|Type1|Type2|TotalCount|Type1Count|Type2Count
1 | a   | b   | 3       |    2      |  1
2 | b   | d   | 4       |    2      |  2
3 | y   | x   | 1       |    0      |  1
```

Currently, I do a groupBy and a Select on the collection:

```
Col.GroupBy(g=>new{g.ID, g.Type1, g.Type2}).Select(s=>new 

{s.Key.ID, s.Key.Type1, s.Key.Type2, TotalCount = s.Sum(x=>x.Count), 

Type1Count = s.Count(x=>x.Type == s.Key.Type1) //addition of individual count severely slows down query
Type2Count = s.Count(x=>x.Type == s.Key.Type2)// same here
}
);
```

As indicated above, the inclusion of Type1Count and Type2Count drastically increases the time the query would take without those columns. I have tried various other ways to get the value of the "Count" column from the initial Col table for each grouped row, but again...performance takes a big hit. Eventually the right results are returned though.

Is there an easier, better and or faster way to achieve the same results?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Out of curiosity, exactly how much slower is it, and how many rows are we talking about?

Comment: It takes less than a second without those lines, and about 2 minutes with them.
The query generated is also very different. With the 2 lines, the query seems to try and search for the types as a repeated query, instead of searching within the initial query (where the Type counts already exists)...if that makes sense

Comment: I hate to be the guy to suggest this, but maybe try a .ToList() in between the .GroupBy() and the .Select()? Whether or not that is possible depends a lot on what you're actually doing, but working on a collection in memory would almost certainly be faster.